# Xamarin Forms Android Navigation Bar Shifting Down

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using a NavigationPage in a Xamarin Forms app. When the page first loads the navigation bar starts partially under the Android status bar (clock, battery, notifications, etc) and then a second or two after the page loads it shifts down to just below the status bar. I like that the status bar icons don't  overlay my navigation bar, but I don't like that the users sees it shift. Is there any way to work around this so that when the page first becomes visible it is already shifted down? Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Can you provide more information and maybe a picture ?

Comment: please add code to investigate, check [ask]

Comment: I didn't provide code because I thought this was a default Xamarin behavior. Apparently it isn't so I'll keep looking into my code. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer a "splash screen" over the awkward bar that appears on the top by default in a Xamarin.Forms app on Android. In my style of splash screen I just have the app's icon floating in the middle of a white field, with NO nav bar on top. If I understand your problem correctly, this workaround would get rid of the first part so there is no longer a "shift". There are many blog posts out there about how to do this, [here is one](http://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2016/august/xamarin-forms-splash-screen-on-android-and-ios/), and [here is my project](https://github.com/KRA2008/cringebot) where I have a splash screen.